# How to download Java SDK from a script?

Tags: sdk, download, java

I've noticed [that](http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/javaruntime.x64/6.0.30) [many](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Launcher_with_automatic_JRE_installation) [scripts](http://svn.dmdirc.com/website/getjava.php) use a URL like the following to download the JRE:

http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=SOMENUMBER

Where do these URLs come from, and are there some available for the JDK?